# Create dynamic link/button to direct to another page in the dashboard

Tags: powerbi

I have a summary matrix in my "Summary" page and detailed KPIs in the "Details" page. This table consists of summarized KPIs for different categories of products in each row. Now I am trying to create a link/button for each row, which will redirect me to the "Details" page with the selected product filter applied on the "Details" page.

I have tried using bookmarks, but since my categories are dynamic, it is not ideal to create manual bookmarks for each category. I have also tried to use "Web URLs" but that would work only for external links, in which case I wont be able to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into [drill through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough) capability.

> With *drill through* in Power BI reports, you can create a page in your report that focuses on a specific entity such as a supplier, customer, or manufacturer. When your report readers use drill through, they right-click a data point in other report pages, and drill through to the focused page to get details that are filtered to that context. You can also [create a button that drills through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drill-through-buttons) to details when they click it.

Comment: Thanks, but this feature exists only in latest version, however my organization uses Jan 2020 version and will not be upgrading anytime soon. 
Any workarounds for this ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Power BI is developing new features pretty quickly so keeping up to date is pretty compelling. I don't have any recommendations other than pushing for a more frequent upgrade schedule as this is far from the only thing you're missing out on.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using drillthrough to achieve this with a small workaround for now. I have added multiple pages as part of drillthrough list. Now I can do "right click->drillthrough->page1, Page2 " etc. However, the drillthough applies only on the selected page, is there a way to sync this selected value across reports?